# Does there always exist a consumption bundle at which the indirect utility function is the inverse of the expenditure function?

Tags: consumer-theory, academic-graduate

Two questions:

1. Given $v(\vec{p},m)$ and $e(\vec{p},\bar{U})$, is there only a single point at which these are inverses of each other?
2. Does an inverse always exist for a given price vector $\vec{p}$, income $m$ and $\bar{U}$, $v$ and $e$?

These are points my mates and I are arguing about as we prepare for our midterm.

Also, I prefer rigorous answers so if you can, feel free to be as thorough as you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding question 1:

From the assumption that the consumer has a single income value $m$, there can only be one value for $m$. So by the notion that $e$ and $v$ are inverses, there can only be one value $e$ for which $m$ corresponds to and thus only one $u$. So there is only one point.

Regarding Question 2:

If we have (1) a utility function that is continuous and locally non-satiated and (2) if $m > 0$ and (3) if both UMP and EMP exist, then they are equivalent. And $e$ and $v$ are inverses.

Claim 1: Solving UMP solves EMP.

Proof:

Suppose bundle $c^*$ solves the UMP but not EMP. Let $c'$ solve EMP. Then (1) amount spent on $c^*$ greater then that on $c'$ and so $u(c') \geq u(c^*) $ because obviously spending more means worse off or same utility. But (2) by local nonsatiation a consumption there exists a bundle $c''$ close enough to $c'$ such that amount spent on $c''$ is less than amount spent on $c^*$ and $u(c'') > u(c^*)$. (3) Contradiction because we assumed $c^*$ solves UMP.

Claim 2: Solving EMP solves UMP.

Proof:

Suppose bundle $c^*$ solves EMP but not UMP. Let $c'$ solve UMP. Then (1) $u(c') > u(c^*)$ even though we spend the same amount on each. That is, $c^*$ doesn't solve UMP since less utility for same $m$.   Because amount spent positive, we can find $t$ where $0<t<1$ such that amount spent on $tc'$ is lower than that spent on $c^*$ yet $u(tc') > u(c^*)$ because $c^*$ does not solve the UMP. (3) Contradiction because we said $c^*$ solved EMP.

Summary:

1. If solutions exist either to UMP or EMP, then solutions exist for the other and they are inverse functions.
2. If an inverse exists, it must be a point.

Comment: This may need a little clean up to become more rigorous. I may have the time to edit it in a couple of hours from now. By the way, It would be good if you would provide some feedback on my excavation activities, here, http://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/3020/how-to-derive-firms-cost-function-from-production-function/5273#5273

Comment: Ah yes. Sorry, been busy with school. I shall respond with specifics but it was excellent.

Answer (score 3):

As regards

**QUESTION 1**
The concept of "inverse" is usually used for a *function*. Here we are dealing not just with two functions, but with two *optimization problems*: "Duality" is, in a sense, the analogous concept of "function inverse",  for optimization problems.

If two optimization problems are dual (in a more or less rigorous sense), then the *solution* of the one is, in a sense, the "inverse" of the solution of the other.

But what is a "solution" in an optimization problem? When the analysis is abstract, the solution does not take on a specific numerical value, but it is a *value function*, i.e. a function that will give us the solution *for any values of the inputs on which the solution depends*.

For the Utility Maximization Problem (UMP), the value function is the **Indirect Utility function**, $v(\mathbf p,m)$. **Abusing notation** (but we gain something from this abuse) we can write

$$v(\mathbf p,m) = \bar U \implies m = v^{-1}(\mathbf p,\bar U)$$

For the Expenditure Minimization Problem (EMP), its value function is the Expenditure function, $e(\mathbf p,\bar{U})$, and

$$e(\mathbf p,\bar{U}) = m \implies \bar U = e^{-1}(\mathbf p,m)$$

Looking at the two we see that

$$v(\mathbf p,m) = e^{-1}(\mathbf p,m),\;\;\; v^{-1}(\mathbf p,\bar U) =e(\mathbf p,\bar{U})$$

So, I wouldn't think that it is correct to say that "they are inverses for a single point". Stretching the concept of "inverse", for *any given* set $(\mathbf p,m)$, the "inverse" Expenditure function is the the Indirect Utility function, and for *any given* set $(\mathbf p,\bar U)$ the "inverse" Indirect Utility function is the Expenditure function.

Note: When the concept of "inverse" is treated in the proper manner (i.e. for univariate functions), then we examine the property *point-by-point* to conclude that it holds.

Comment: +1 The definition of value function you have given matches what I have read in the literature. But I don't understand how this is different from the defintion of a function. Can you elaborate on this? One thing that does strike me is the following: consider $$v = U(x^*(p_x,p_y,m),y^*(p_x,p_y,m))$$ This is a map between $$\Bbb{R^3} \mapsto \Bbb{R}^2  \mapsto \Bbb{R}^1$$ so it is really a composition of functions in some ways except that the optimal demand function is a vector-valued function

Comment: The "value function" of an optimizing problem is the objective function of the problem, but where the argument(s) of itare no longer the decision variables of the problem, but the _optimal determination rules_ of these decision variables, expressed in terms of the _exogenous_ parameters/variables.